# Smart math regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, performance, math, knockout.js

I know there are smart ppl out there. At the moment, I want to use one single and the most elegant regular expression to separate numbers to achieve some really simple math calculation.

It needs support some fuzzy number guessing for example:

1+.2 should equiv to 1 + 0.2

.1-.2 should equiv to 0.1 - 0.2

-.2+-100.2 should equiv to -0.2 - 100.2

`Here is a quick demo I made up for you to play around
http://jsfiddle.net/av57A/60/`

Is that possible to achieve those logic in one elegant regular expression?

Thanks.

Comment: i got scared looking at that fiddle

Comment: Thanks @jcalloway. Here is an updated version http://jsfiddle.net/452QF/16/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it.  Nice practice in regex for me.  Also thanks for showing me jsfiddle.  Never seen anything like that b4.

---

```
reg1 : ^[\-\d{1,}|\-*\.*\d*+]{1,}
reg2 (g) : \.{2}
reg3 (g) : ^(([\-]{0,})(\d*\.*\d*)?)|([\+\-\*\/]{1,})|((\d*)+(\.*\d*)?)

---
2-1  :  2 | - | 1
.1+.2  :  0.1 | + | 0.2
.2+1  :  0.2 | + | 1
-1-1.3  :  -1 | - | 1.3
2+1  :  2 | + | 1
-2+1  :  -2 | + | 1
2+-1  :  2 | + | -1
1+1.1  :  1 | + | 1.1
2.1+1  :  2.1 | + | 1
-1.0-1.3  :  -1 | - | 1.3
-1-.3  :  -1 | - | 0.3
```

Comment: @Jing If this answers your question.  Please upvote my answer.  I'm looking for stackoverflow cred :)

Comment: @Jing regardless of your reputation, you should be able to mark an answer as "correct". Which you should ;-)